# gnome-terminal hangs on start in KDE

Tags: kde, gnome-terminal

I have multiple desktops installed (Ubuntu 12.10), and while logged in with KDE I see the following strange behaviour. When starting gnome-terminal, it opens a window with the title and menu rendered, but no content. The background is the same as the frame, and hangs. The menu will not respond, and the window will not close cleanly (not responding to close signal). If I launch it from another terminal, there is no output . If I start it as root (sudo gnome-terminal) it runs fine. It works properly when using Unity DM as a normal user, but not KDE. I should also add that I'm using KDM instead of LightDM.

I'd really like to run GNOME Terminal rather than Konsole in KDE as I'm trying to get around the SSH askpass integration problems in Konsole (keyring integration, etc). I'd also like it to work just on principle.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get around the ssh askpass integration problems in konsole (keyring integration, etc). I'd also like it to work just on principle.